# Cleaning up resources in catch block?

Tags: c#, exception

I'm attempting to read and load some data into a disposable type that internally has certain native memory allocated. However things could fail, and in case they do, I need to Dispose of the objects (perhaps one actually succeeded, but the second did not). Here's my solution:

```
static void LoadData(string path, DisposableTypeA a, DisposableTypeB b)
{
    try
    {
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(path, FileMode.Open)))
        {
            a.LoadFrom(reader);
            b.LoadFrom(reader);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        a.Dispose();
        b.Dispose();
        throw;
    }
}
```

Something feels off about my approach, but I can't think of any other way and I can't really find much info about ever cleaning up inside a catch block. Is there something wrong with my solution, and is there perhaps a neater way?

Normally I would prefer to use error codes - i.e. something like
`if (!a.LoadFrom(reader)) a.Dispose()`, but such a solution will fail if there's an exception. A slight modification I can think of is to essentially do the catch and rethrow inside the LoadFrom like

```
public void LoadFrom(BinaryReader reader)
{
    try
    {
        // Some code
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        this.Dispose();
        throw;
    }
}
```

but it still feels a bit off.

Comment: What feels off about this is that `LoadData` is disposing resources it doesn't own. As a consumer, I wouldn't expect that after calling `LoadData`, `a` and `b` would be disposed in cases of errors. The caller, the owner of the resources, normally disposes whatever resource it has

Comment: The caller of `LoadFrom` should have a `using` like this `using (var a = CreateDisposableTypeA()) using (var b = CreateDisposableTypeA()) { LoadFrom(path, a, b) }` do not dispose outer parameters within your function

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto So something like ```try { loader.LoadData(path, a); } catch{ a.Dispose(); }``` from inside the caller? Does that make sense? I guess my initial approach was motivated by something like"try load, clean up if fails" - the caller doesn't do anything, it just assumes all went well, or the data loading failed. It's not responsible for whatever the Loading method did/failed etc.

Comment: @Charlieface I can't do that - the disposable type instance needs to exist for an indefinite  amount of time.

Comment: The caller is at fault ultimately. It needs to manage its own resources. Whether or not this function failed, it needs to do so. If the object needs to exist for longer than the caller, then the caller needs to setup a mechanism for disposable, such as storing ina field and being *itself* disposable. And why would you only cleanup on failure, why not cleanup on success also?

Comment: @Charlieface The caller is disposable, and a,b are its fields. Loading them using LoadData is one way of initializing them, but there are other fallback possibilities. If the loading succeeds nothing has to be done - eventually a,b will be disposed when the caller object is, but I don't know when that will be. If loading fails, I need to dispose of the possibly partially loaded data, and try a fallback method.

Comment: Then why are `a` and `b` not created within `LoadFrom`? Or the caller should have a `try` `catch`. Either way, the current design is somewhat of an anti-pattern

Comment: @Charlieface You're right, that's confusing. It should be ```a=LoadFrom(reader)``` + a slight modification to the LoadFrom code, e.g. ```someLocalVariable.Dispose()``` rather than ```this.Dispose()```etc. Do you think it then seems alright?

Sorry for the confusion.